# When avoiding nulls in PHP, can I reimplement isset?

Tags: php, null

I'm running into the problem that I think everyone runs into with null: that is, there are different kinds of null. It could mean "empty", "unchanged", "unset", "unknown", or any number of things. And I am to the point where I need to distinguish between them somehow.

Basically I have a database manager part of my program that receives an object representing data to be updated in the database from from another part of my program that is responsible for validating form data and converting it into said object (Which has one of a several different classes with specific predefined properties). I need some way to distinguish between a "null" property in that object which means "I actually want the value null stored in the database" and a different type of "null" which means "If there is an existing value in the database don't change it". Of the two, the latter is going to be by far the more common case, but I need some way to allow for the former as well.

My current thought, which would seem the best for this situation, is to create a new class which represents each "type" of null, for example an `Unchanged` class verses a `SetToNull` type or something like that. Then I could set the property to an instance of one of those classes.

The only issue is that I would like a function that behaves similar to the existing `isset()` function in that it would allow me to check both if a given property exists and also if it has a real value (as opposed to one of my new null types) in one simple statement.

I'm aware I can do something like this:

```php
if (isset($thing->property) && !($thing->property instanceof Unchanged || $thing->property instanceof SetToNull)){
    // do whatever
}
```

However, that's obviously not ideal because it's long and unwieldy, and I don't want to have that everywhere all over my code base. I'd prefer something like this:

```php
if (myCustomIsset($thing->property)){
    // do whatever
}
```

However, `isset` doesn't seem to be a normal function; somehow it suppresses warnings if the property hasn't been defined or something like that, so I'm not sure how to implement something like that myself.

Comment: What are the two nulls that are sent? One is `null`, but what is this second `null` that is to just not change? What is the difference between the two? Basically, how do you diffirentiate between a null that wants the DB value to be a NULL or a null that doesnt want to change anything?

Comment: For most of the program, there is no difference. The only real difference is, when I save the data back to the database, should I save a null value, or should I not save anything and let it retain any existing value that may be in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that comes to mind which I have done in the past is two pass in two arguments. The first argument is the object by itself. The second argument is a string that contains the property name.

Here is an example:

```
function MyCustomIsset($object, $property) {
    return isset($object->$property) && !($object->$property instanceof Unchanged || $object->$property instanceof SetToNull);
}
```

And here is how you would use it:

```
if (myCustomIsset($thing, "property")){
    // do whatever
}
```

Since you aren't referencing the property of the object when you pass it in, PHP won't throw an error. In the body of the function, you reference the property using the passed in string argument. You can reference the property using a special feature of PHP called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would not change the model. The model should represent the data in the database, and the values of its properties should be the same as the values of the columns those properties represent.

I would look at changing how the model gets its data. It sounds like you're instantiating the model from the form data, which doesn't include values for every property because the form only updates certain properties.

If you instantiate the model instead by selecting it from the database, and then modify it with the form data before validating and saving it, it will have the correct values for every property, and null will unambiguously mean null.

Comment: You make a really good point. Unfortunately in my situation, with the way I have validation working, that is a little more challenging than it sounds because the validator doesn't have access to the original values, as I've tried to keep those parts of my code very separate from one another. Maybe you're right though, and I'll have to rework the validator a bit...

Comment: As I think about this a little more, this is probably what I'm actually going to do. I'm leaving Kodos Johnson as the accepted answer because it answers the question I actually asked, but this answer avoids the problem altogether and is a good solution to my underlying problem.